# How to divide into two functions?

Tags: python

For a basic computer science class in python we're writing a program that reads in a file, translates the file to pig latin and writes the translation in a new file, and counts the number of lines and words translated.

```
file_path = raw_input("Enter a file pathway: ")
f_input = file(file_path, "r")
f_output = file("pig_output.txt","w")

vowels = ("a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U")


def piglat_trans():
    line_count = 0
    word_count = 0
    for line in f_input:
        words = line.split(" ")
        pig_line = ""
        line_count += 1
        for word in words:
            word = word.strip("\n")
            word_count += 1
            if word[0] in vowels:
                pig_word = word + "way"
            elif word[0] not in vowels and word[1] not in vowels and len(word)>1:
                pig_word = word [2:len(word)] + word[0] + word[1] + "ay"
            else:
                pig_word = word[1:len(word)] + word[0] + "ay"
            pig_line += pig_word + " "
        f_output.write(pig_line + "\n")
    print "Translation finished and written pig_output.txt"
    print "A total of " + str(line_count) + " lines were translated successfully."
    print "A total of " + str(word_count) + " words were translated successfully."


piglat_trans()

f_input.close()
f_output.close()
```

The program works fine, but I'm supposed to make the line/word count and the printing parts separate functions from the translator itself.  How would I do this?

Thanks for the help!
** Edit: also I've been having a problem with spaces and tabs with the translation and it returns:

```
line 25, in piglat_trans if word[0] in vowels:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: For the last error, consider that `'a  b'.split(" ")` will return `['a', '', 'b']`; you probably want the just `.split()` with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this is a homework, I won't write code.

Looks like your key logic lies in the most inner for-loop, where you take a word and pig_latinify it.

And after that, you just need a mapper function for mapping every word of the source to a pig-latinified version of the text. This function can also count the number of lines.

And, try to make your file handlers short lived, and use a context manager(`with` statement in Python).

Here is what I'd do:

```
def pigify(word):
    ....
    return pig

def pigify_text(text):
    ...
    pig_words = map(pigify, words)
    ...
    return (pig_text, word_count, line_count)

with open(infile) as f:
    text = f.read()

pig, wc, lc = pigify_text(text)

with open(outfield, "w") as f:
     f.write(pig)

print wc
print lc
```